# Error related to labels when tuning catboost in tidymodels

Tags: r, tidymodels, catboost

Here is the model:

```
cb_spec <- boost_tree(
  mode = "classification",
  trees = 1000,
  tree_depth = tune(),
  min_n = tune(),
  mtry = tune(),
  learn_rate = tune()
) %>%
  set_engine("catboost", loss_function = "Logloss", task_type = "GPU")
```

Here is the recipe:

```
cb_rec <- recipe(covid_vaccination ~ ., data = cb_train) %>% 
  step_unknown(all_nominal_predictors()) %>%
  #step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors(), one_hot = TRUE) %>%
  step_impute_median(all_numeric_predictors()) %>% 
  step_nzv(all_predictors())
```

I combine them:

```
cb_wf <- workflow() %>% 
  add_model(cb_spec) %>% 
  add_recipe(cb_rec)
```

Then I try to tune to find optimal hyperparameters:

```
cb_tune <- tune_grid(
  object = cb_wf,
  resamples = cb_folds,
  grid = cb_grid,
  metrics = metric_set(roc_auc),
  control = control_grid(verbose = TRUE)
)
```

Here is the error I get:

> Error in catboost.from_matrix(as.matrix(float_and_cat_features_data),
> : Unsupported label type, expecting double or integer.

I have already confirmed that categorical variables are changed to factors. There are absolutely no character type vectors in my dataset.

Comment: I get the error: `Error: Engine 'catboost' is not supported for "boost_tree()". See "show_engines('boost_tree")".`

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example?

Comment: Sorry this was recently solved in catboost github with a reproducible example, I can link the issue if you would like. But I am going to close this question.

Comment: I see.. but now you are getting [the same error](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/1874#issuecomment-936713748) I mentioned above.

Comment: yep. interesting. Hopefully Glemhel fixes that for us soon. I have a feeling the 1.0.0 catboost release messed some stuff up.

Comment: @captcoma, remove and reinstall your packages, reinstall the treesnip fork especially. Glemhel said it is working for him and it seems to be working on my end too now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/1874

Solved thanks to someone awesome who made their own fork of treesnip as a workaround: Mikhail Rudakov

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).